# Memory Usage of Empty Unity Project on Android Platform

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, memory

When I create an empty Unity project and build it for the Android platform, it typically consumes around 130-165MB of memory. Is this memory usage normal for an empty project on Android?

It appears that there may be potential ways to optimize the memory usage and reduce the overall footprint of the project.

Unity version：2021.3.20f1c1